# Reading Configuration File in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I hope I can sum up my question with as much detail as possible. I am new to NodeJS so be nice :D

I am writing an app in node that will allow people to see stats on their Plex Media Libraries. I am storing my configuration in a file `config.ini`. Settings in the file include: the url base of the application, the port the app will run on, their Plex username & password, number of movies or episodes to display on the index and a few other settings. I have a config template & route that allows them to update these settings and the file get updated with the new values.

My problem lies with how do I get this file to be read dynamically by Node. When the person updates the config thru my `config.js` router it takes restarting the app to get the new values read. (Somethings like url_base/port need to have the app restarted, I'll take care of this later) but simple things like changing the amount of movies or episodes to display shouldn't need a restart.

For example take a look at my `index.js` route which displays a small amount of information:

```
var express = require('express');
var Q       = require('q');
var util    = require('util');

// Define router
var router = express.Router();

// Load config
var UserConfiguration = require('../lib/config');
var config = new UserConfiguration();

// Load plex
var Plex = require('../lib/plex');
var plexClient = new Plex({
    hostname: config.getPlexHost(),
    port: config.getPlexPort(),
    username: config.getPlexUser(),
    password: config.getPlexPassword(),
    token: config.getPlexAuthToken()
});

// Plex is down or we couldn't get in
if(plexClient.ping() !== true) {
    res.render('pages/index', {
        page_title: 'home',
        plexRecentMovies: null,
        plexRecentEpisodes: null
    });
}

// Retrieve new episodes, pass in config setting for limit
function recentlyAddedEpisodes(req, res, next) {
    var recentEpisodes = plexClient.shows()
    .then(function (showSection) {
        return showSection.key;
    })
    .then(function(key) {
        plexClient.getRecentlyAddedEpisodes(key, config.getRecentEpisodes())
        .then(function(episodes) {
            req.recentlyAddedEpisodes = episodes;
            return next();
        });
    });
}

// Retrieve new movies, pass in config setting for limit
function recentlyAddedMovies(req, res, next) {
    var recentMovies = plexClient.movies()
    .then(function (movieSection) {
        return movieSection.key;
    })
    .then(function(key) {
        plexClient.getRecentlyAddedMovies(key, config.getRecentMovies())
        .then(function(movies) {
            req.recentlyAddedMovies = movies;
            return next();
        });
    });
}

function renderIndexPage(req, res) {
    res.render('pages/index', {
        page_title: 'home',
        plexRecentMovies: req.recentlyAddedMovies,
        plexRecentEpisodes: req.recentlyAddedEpisodes
    });
}

// Finally render the template
router.get('/',
    recentlyAddedEpisodes,
    recentlyAddedMovies,
    renderIndexPage
);

module.exports = router;
```

I am positive I am not doing this the correct way because everything outside of the router.get() seems to be cached, so the new values never get applied even thou I make calls to config.getSomeSetting() in my other two functions.

Thanks for any help, let me know if I should provide any more information.

Comment: Looks to me like you need something similar to a db connector for a config file.

Answer (score 0):

You could switch to json instead of ini and then use my `json-update` module.